# Python syntax error in identation?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am trying to understand some code.
In code below there is a syntax error but I really don't know what.

```
def parse(data):
print(data)

def get_set(json_url):
url = json_url
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

s_code = '0'

print data
s_code = data["statusCode"]
print s_code

    seconds_waiting = 10
       if s_code == 200:
    url = json_url
               response = urllib.urlopen(url)
               data = json.loads(response.read())

            parse(data)
elif s_code != 200:

    print "waiting " + str(seconds_waiting) + " second(s)..."
               time.sleep(seconds_waiting)
            get_set(json_url)

get_set(json_url):
```

Comment: There's tons of errors in there, what's the question?

Comment: The question is pointless here; the answer is obvious, *[read the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)*.

Comment: Whic errors are there?

Comment: SMH... What is this?

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax it's Delirious Syntax

Comment: @cat Awesome love it! Thanks for making my day XD

Comment: user1938193 - The Indentation is how you define the bodies of methods as well as conditional statements (as opposed to other languages that use opening/closing brackets, etc) - your incorrect indentation is why it was broken.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a Python beautifier could have fixed this problem... even `pylint` could have told you the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrected (?):

```
def parse(data):
    print(data)

def get_set(json_url):
    url = json_url
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())

    s_code = '0'

    print data
    s_code = data["statusCode"]
    print s_code

    seconds_waiting = 10
    if s_code == 200:
        url = json_url
        response = urllib.urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(response.read())
        parse(data)
    elif s_code != 200:
        print "waiting " + str(seconds_waiting) + " second(s)..."
        time.sleep(seconds_waiting)
        get_set(json_url)
```

Indentation is one of the major features / requirements in Python. If the above code was in a class it would need to be indented once again. But as pointed out in the comments, please [read the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) (again).

Answer (score 5):

Most of the issues where just the code being improperly formatted (Indentation is used to define the bodies of methods and conditional statements within Python)

Here is the code

```
def parse(data):
    print(data)


def get_set(json_url):
    url = json_url
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())

    s_code = '0'

    print data
    s_code = data["statusCode"]
    print s_code

    seconds_waiting = 10
    if s_code == 200:
        url = json_url
        response = urllib.urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(response.read())

        parse(data)
    elif s_code != 200:
        print "waiting " + str(seconds_waiting) + " second(s)..."
        time.sleep(seconds_waiting)
        get_set(json_url)
```

Comment: That answer was posted just before mine, I did not see other answer when posting.

Comment: Upvoted yours as well.

Comment: The function get set should not be indentated?

Answer (score 3):

As there were a lot of indentation errors, I propose you one of the possible solutions:

```
def parse(data):
    print(data)

def get_set(json_url):
    url = json_url
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    s_code = '0'
    print data
    s_code = data["statusCode"]
    print s_code
    seconds_waiting = 10
    if s_code == 200:
        url = json_url
        response = urllib.urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(response.read())
        parse(data)
    elif s_code != 200:
        print "waiting " + str(seconds_waiting) + " second(s)..."
        time.sleep(seconds_waiting)
        get_set(json_url)
```

P.S. I was not checking the logic of program(fixed only indentation)